# Disabling (fade in and fade out) dialog box animation

Tags: android, dialog

I'm novice programmist and I have problem with disabling dialog box animation (fade in and fade out).

I tried to to it using empty style and set it by changing

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

into

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.NoAnimation));
```

Background of dialog box became black, positive and negatice button changed into <2.1 - 4.0) android style, but fade in and fade out animation effect remained...

My style:

```
<style name="DialogNoAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/enter</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/exit</item>
</style>

<style name="NoAnimation" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogNoAnimation</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas how can I eliminate this animation?

Comment: Have you tried to add `@null` for enter and exit animation instead?

Comment: or `<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>`

Comment: Exact as same effect as with @anim/enter and @anim/exit. I mean with          <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item> and 
<item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@null</item> or <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally success!

res/anim/enter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
```

res/anim/exit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
```

res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="DialogNoAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/enter</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/exit</item>
</style>
```

src/[dialog_box_class].java

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
  super.onStart();
  if (getDialog() == null)
    return;
  getDialog().getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogNoAnimation);
}
```

Comment: The only problem that I had with this solution was when you re-enter the app and then dismiss the dialog. My solution was to use getDialog().getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogWithAnimation); with a post delay in onResume

Comment: @AntonMakov what happened when you re-enter?

Answer (score 10):

here's a simple solution:

define a custom style on your styles.xml:

```
<style name="Dialog">
  <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
  //... more items
</style>
```

Create a new builder with your custom style:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.Dialog);
builder.setTitle("Dialog title");
builder.show();
```

enjoy